# Listing of files in directory in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am having list of xml files in a folder like - data0.xml, data1.xml, data2.xml, ...data99.xml

I have to read the contents of these files for further processing. Currently I am using for loop like below

```
for xmlentry in `ls -v *.xml
do
        execute_loop $xmlemtry
done
```

This is executing fine for all xml's file in sequence ,

But I wanted to know if I want to force FOR loop to start from data10.xml and proceed till data99.xml

For loop shoud start from data10.xml, data11.xml .... data99.xml

> How to do something like this in shell scripting, better if I could
>   control the start of loop with a variable

Comment: Do you mean control interactively, like a command which asks you "This one?" until you answer yes?

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the name of the files and loop through them. In you specific example, something like this could work:

```
first=10
last=99
for i in $(seq "$first" "$last")
do
    xmlfile="data${i}.xml"
    execute_loop "$xmlfile"
done
```

Comment: thanks for the response, I have the input as "data10.xml" so I know that I should start for-loop from this xml file. I donot get the integer as input. I may have to extract integer from string first for this purpose